# Transaction in Spring with datasources create in runtime

Tags: spring, transactions

I have a problem with transaction in spring, because in my project datasources are created in runtime from side files and according to [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

I should inject to `TransactionManager dataSource` and made it visible for annotation `@Transactional` using `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>`.

So my question is how can I do it when I want to use annotation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all how are you creating the datasources at runtime. 
if directly as `Datasource=new datasource...` I will suges use BeanDefinitionBuilder in Spring 3.2 to Create the `Datasourcebean` and then register it via `BeanDefinitionRegistry`. 
and then get the bean from Spring context and it will be considered using the transaction.